# Importing IIS configuration causes IIS to hang

Tags: windows, iis

We're migrating our development machines from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and on one of our new machines we want to import the IIS configuration from 7 into the machine.

Here's what we've tried:

Open IIS Manager
Open "Shared Configuration"
Check "Enable shared configuration"
Click the button next to "Physical path" field and navigate to the folder holding our configration settings.
Click "Apply"

The system hangs. No errors in the Event Viewer.

Anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?
Thanks

Comment: That's the wrong way to "migrate". Please learn Web Deploy and then sync the configuration over, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/synchronize-iis Note that don't use packages, and simply connect both machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not recommended while the different version of IIS could have different default module installed.

I suggest you could try to use webdeploy or third-party tool to help you migrate the sites from IIS7 to IIS10.

Detials about how to migrate the sites from II7 to IIS10, you could refer to this [article](https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/steps-to-migrate-multiple-iis-sites/).

Besides, I suggest you could also try this [migrate tool](https://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2013/04/iis-easy-migration-tool-iemt).

Comment: This was a great lead, thanks! The difference in versions was the root.
In my case, I simply exported the "default" working configuration from newer IIS and then compared it with my old one and moved things over in text editor.
One of biggest things was new encryption provider, but that can also be done in similar way, simply add the password to new IIS and export to see how new config looks.